# Compute ratios of elements in two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, say `a` and `b`, both of length `n`.  I'd like to compute the following:

- minimum of $a[i]/b[i]$  where $i=1, 2, ...n$ and $b[i]>0$

I'd also like to know the index of the element where the min occurs.

Comment: Do you want the i to be from the original list? Or the list of ratios with the b[i]=0 indices removed?

Comment: I want the i from the original list.

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 10000;
{a, b} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, n}];
```

This may be quite fast:

```
r = a/b; Position[r, min = Min@Pick[r, Positive@b]]
min
```

> ```
> {{7955}}
> -850.273
> ```

Comment: But Kuba  you can't do the division "a/b" in first place if there was a zero in list "b" ? A check is needed before

Comment: @Nasser If you won't tell anybody then it is ok :P because later only `Positive` `b` positions are picked. So even `ComplexInfinity` is not a problem. But it is good point to keep in mind, for a general approach/condition.

Answer (score 2):

One way to enforce the positivity condition on `b` is to locate the positions of all the positive elements of `b` and use those to index into the division of `a` by `b`.

```
a = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10];
b = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10];
pos = Flatten[Position[b, _?(0 < # &)]]
Min[a[[pos]]/b[[pos]]]
```

Comment: But Bill you can't do the division "a/b" in first place if there was a zero in list "b" ? A check is needed before.

Comment: No it is not ignored, try `Min[{1, 2/0}]` it looks ignored because in `pos` there are no entries with `b=0`.

Comment: I've rearranged things so it now only does the division on the nonzero terms.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

After Kuba appropriate comment (and using his code for picking Min) to deal with positive denominator:

```
f[a_, b_] := Quiet[{s = Position[a/b, Min@Pick[a/b, Positive@b]], 
  Extract[(a/b), First@s]}]
```

Note test case with two cases:

```
f[{1, 2, 3, 3}, {1, -1, 2, 3}]
```

yields:

> {{{1}, {4}}, 1}

The `First@s` just to  displaythe (unique) value of minimum. 
`Quiet` to suppress errors of Indeterminate for 0/0 and ComplexInfinity nonzero/0. Still works for these cases.

Comment: @Kuba fair enough

Comment: I mean, I like that approach, just correct it so it fits the OP's need :)

Comment: @Kuba I appreciate feedback and have modified code, purloing your code (with attribution):)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10];
b = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10];
lst = a/b;

Min[lst]
(*0.442821447015283*)

Position[lst, Min[lst]]
(* {{4}} *)
```

**Update to answer comment below**

`How can I implement the b[i]>0 condition`

One way can be to use [MapThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) to make the list by checking for the condition

```
a = {2, 9, 5, 3, 0, 4, 9, 1};
b = {0, -4, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0, 10};
lst = MapThread[If[#2 > 0, #1/#2, Sequence @@ {}] &, {a, b}]

(*{5/2, 0, 1, 1/10}*)

Min[lst]
(* 0 *)

Position[lst, %]
{{2}}
```

**Updated to return position of min in original list not filtered list**

remember the index while filtering to use it to go back.

```
a = {2, 9, 5, 3, 0, 4, 9};
b = {0, -4, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0};
i = 0;
lst = MapThread[(i++; If[#2 > 0, {i, #1/#2}, Sequence @@ {}]) &, {a,b}]

(* {{3, 5/2}, {5, 0}, {6, 1}, {8, 1/10}} *)

min = Min[lst[[All, 2]]]
(* 0 *)

p = Flatten@Position[lst[[All, 2]], min];
lst[[p, 1]]
(* {5} *)
```

A short hand version is

```
i = 0;
p = Flatten@
 Position[lst[[All,2]],Min@MapThread[(i++;If[#2>0,{i,#1/#2},Sequence@@{}])&,{a,b}][[All,2]]]
lst[[p, 1]]
```

Comment: How can I implement the b[i]>0 condition?

Comment: The actual position is 5, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by first combining the lists using Transpose, and then filtering the division pairs using either a pattern with `Cases` or a predicate using `Select`

```
Cases[Transpose[{a, b}], {_, _?Positive}]
```

or

```
Select[Transpose[{a, b}], #[[2]] > 0&]
```

This will return the filtered list of `{numerator, denominator}` pairs, to get the divisions I would just expand on the above with Map Apply (`@@@`)

```
lst = Divide @@@ Cases[Transpose[{a, b}], {_, _?Positive}]
```

or

```
lst = Divide @@@ Select[Transpose[{a, b}, #[[2]] > 0&]
```

This will give back a list with the defined ratios. You can then just use `Min` and `Position` as other answers have shown.

Answer (score 1):

If the minimum can be assumed to be unique then use `f1`, which returns the position of only the first occurrence of the minimum value. Otherwise use `f2`, which is slower but returns the positions of all occurrences.

```
f1[a_,b_] := With[{i = Ordering[#1,1][[1]]}, {#1[[i]],#2[[i]]}]& [a[[#]]/b[[#]],#]& @
                  SparseArray[UnitStep[-b], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"];
f2[a_,b_] := With[{m = Min[#1]}, {m,Pick[#2,#1,m]}]& [a[[#]]/b[[#]],#]& @
                  SparseArray[UnitStep[-b], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"];
n = 7;
a = {2, 9, 5, 3,  0, 0, 9};
b = {0,-4, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0};
f1[a,b]
f2[a,b]
```

> {0, 5}
>   {0, {5, 6}}

Comment: Ray, would you mind to add some definitions of `a`, `b` etc. to make evaluation unambiguous?